# Vi piace 'la quadra', o preferite 'la quadratura'?

Tags: grammar

... io preferisco 'la quadratura', ma ormai sempre più spesso sento, o leggo, 'la quadra'.

Così, sono a chiedere,

1. qual è l'origine di 'la quadra'?
2. ritenete che usare 'la quadra' sia volgare o poco accademico?
3. pensate che 'la quadra' sia più diffusa in alcune regione pittosto che in altre?

Anche se appaiono le cosiddette 'ultime parole famose', ecco un esempio tratto da *bergamonews* del 6 aprile 2010: '*È stata una riunione importante, abbiamo trovato *la quadra* sul metodo per fare le riforme*'.

Comment: Prima volta che lo sento dire. Per dirla tutta... non avrei nemmeno usato *quadratura* in quella frase...

Comment: @nico, e perche' non avresti usato 'quadratura'?

Comment: Non so, non mi suona bene... Lo userei in un'espressione del tipo *la quadratura del bilancio* ma non direi *la quadratura sul metodo*.

Comment: Mai sentito “quadra”.

Comment: Mio marito è emiliano, usa il vocabolo "quadra" da sempre, per cui penso che nella sua regione sia piuttosto diffuso. Buffo che io, veneta, non l'avessi mai sentito usare prima di conoscerlo, eppure la distanza in chilometri non era molta.

Answer (score 16):

Rispondo brevemente.

1. Ci si riferisce spesso alla *quadratura del cerchio* come a un problema difficile da risolvere.
2. Usare *la quadra* per *la quadratura* è da ignoranti.
3. È una parola molto recente; pronunciata da un noto uomo politico, di livello culturale modesto, è stata poi abusata dai giornalisti.

---

Più interessante è sapere perché *quadratura del cerchio* è sinonimo di problema difficile o impossibile.

Nella geometria classica, l'uso della riga e del compasso (strumenti teorici e astratti, ovviamente) garantiva l'esistenza della soluzione. Molti problemi classici di cui non si possedeva una soluzione mediante una costruzione con riga e compasso erano già stati risolti con altri mezzi; per esempio, la prima quadratura del cerchio risale a Dinostrato (quarto secolo AC) mediante una curva già usata da Ippia per la trisezione dell'angolo. Si veda http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratrice.

La quadratura del cerchio consiste nel costruire un quadrato avente la stessa area di un cerchio dato. Per ventiquattro secoli il problema di trovare una costruzione con riga e compasso sfidò i matematici. Solo nel diciannovesimo secolo Wantzel escogitò un metodo per tradurre i problemi di costruzione con riga e compasso in linguaggio algebrico e dimostrò che la trisezione dell'angolo (con riga e compasso) non è possibile. Nel 1882 Lindemann sistemò la questione della quadratura del cerchio dimostrando che π (rapporto tra area del cerchio e quadrato del raggio) è un numero *trascendente* e quindi, attraverso il metodo di Wantzel, che la quadratura del cerchio con riga e compasso è impossibile.

Comment: Tuttavia *abbiamo trovato la **quadratura** sul metodo per fare le riforme* non vorrebbe comunque dire nulla... se l'intenzione è quella di dire *abbiamo trovato un accordo sul metodo per fare le riforme*.

Comment: @nico Nemmeno io lo direi, ma non lo trovo scorretto: significa “abbiamo trovato la soluzione del problema”.

Comment: non so, "la quadratura" così da solo? Possibile, ma brutto.

Comment: @nico, ormai qualsiasi cosa nella lingua italiana può non significare nulla, oppure può avere un numero indefinito di significati, in particolare quando l'intendimento di chi parla, o scrive, è esattamente quello di parlare, o scrivere, senza dire nulla, o, ancora peggio, quando l'intendimento ê quello di dissimulare quanto si pensa realmente.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: ragione in più per parlare italiano correttamente!